# Consuming JSON Web Services in ASP.NET?

Tags: api, rest, vbscript, asp-classic

I have old ASP.NET web site written in VB that
needs to communicate with Ruby web service.

I don't need to write web service by myself, just need best approach or some library to communicate with REST API.

Answer (score 0):

I  am not sure what's the problem with my question!?
Here is the answer that I will post by myself :

```
 private function getJSON(fromURL as string) as string
     dim objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

                objXML.Open ("GET", fromURL, false )
         objXML.Send
        return CType(objXML.responseText, String)
    end function
```